# ssh encoding from ubuntu client to ubuntu server wrong

Tags: ssh, locale, encoding

I login to my server via ssh.
Any umlaut is displayed incorrectly:
[image: example]

Server Default locale:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
```

Server  *locale*:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

What can I do to correct this?

Comment: What's does the `locale` command output on the machine you log in from?

Comment: have a look @ the update

Comment: Ok.. And what about the `locale` output on the server?

Comment: its the servers locale

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is the following command to set the locale of the console:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Ensure the encoding is set to UTF-8, rather than ISO-8859-* or something else. Hopefully your issue is as simple as this.

Comment: I suspect it is something like that. Or the encoding in the terminal program such as gnome-terminal.

Comment: Have you tried using something like Xterm instead?

Comment: after doing this on my server it does not boot anymore. it says "mountall main process terminated with status 2. fs check or mount failed" and drops to maintenance shell.

Comment: That's weird, but it sounds like a filesystem corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: The (unspecified) ssh client speaks and listens ISO 8859, whereas server speaks UTF.
Solution: **Make the ssh client software speak and listen UTF-8.**
Still little information on the client-side setup so explicit directions do not seem possible.